# Mold growing on the pot surface

Tags: containers, potting-soil, mold

On the surface of this pot there have been this mold growing.

[image]

The color varies from yellow-white to bright yellow. Is it dangerous for the plant, can it spread to the other pots I have in the house and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

The growths are not dangerous to you or your plant, but they are unpleasant to look at in a houseplant - some improvements in cultural conditions would help.

It's difficult to tell from the image whether the fungal growth has appeared on debris (such as woody bits) on the top of the soil, or whether it's just growing from the soil directly. If it's appeared on surface debris, remove the debris, but if you used a rather lumpy potting soil with small bits of debris in it, that is not an option. What soil did you  use in the pot, was it a proprietary potting soil, or something else such as garden soil?

These kind of growths are often associated with overly wet or damp soil conditions which might be caused by overwatering or by poor drainage/poor airflow. The soil level in the pot is rather too low, being quite a distance from the rim of the pot - it should be sitting at a quarter inch, and no more than half an inch below the rim maximum to allow air to flow across it. It's also important that the pot has drainage holes; if the pot does not have drainage holes, repot into something that does, this time making sure the soil level is  not too low.

The soil does not look obviously wet, but watering should only be done when the top of the soil is dry to the touch, at which point, water well, allowing the excess to drain away freely from the bottom of the pot,then replace into  an outer pot or saucer after about 30 minutes, when it's stopped flowing out so the pot is not left sitting in water.

Answer (score 2):

White molds are not dangerous to the plants. At least till date nothing such has been documented. However it is an indication of a problem, primarily `over watering`, which in turn can add to the rotting of the roots and if that continues the plant will die eventually.

It would be good to check if the drainage channels in the pot are working properly, if not they needs clearing.

Though white molds are not dangerous to the plants they can cause many health problems, such as `respiratory infections`. Molds can be hazardous for patients with respiratory problem like asthma.

Comment: It is inaccurate to definitively state that 'molds are hazardous for patients with respiratory problem like asthma'. The air we breathe is laced with fungal spores everywhere, they are a normal component of air, and when you breath in, you are inhaling around 40 spores with every breath. Some people may have a sensitivity or an allergy to certain moulds,, but not necessarily those who have respiratory issues, though some may have a problem with them.

Comment: Thank you @Bamboo for educating. Will the presence of excess molds increase their amount than the normal condition? If so it could be hazardous for the folks with breathing problem. Am I still getting it wrong?

Comment: The only incorrect thing you said was to state that molds 'ARE hazardous for patients with respiratory problems' - if you'd said 'might' or 'can' be hazardous, that would have been fine, because not all people are mold sensitive, but some may be. For example, I'm only sensitive to moulds if  I eat them (such as in blue cheese or penicillin) but not otherwise, even though I do have respiratory problems. Even so, the presence of such a small amount in the pot in a normal sized room with airflow is unlikely to cause serious health issues, especially as I suspect this might  be a  slime mould.

Comment: Make sense, I have updated the post. Thank you. Please feel free to edit if there are any other corrections needed.